# How to prove that a non-negative nat is positive in J-Bob?

Tags: j-bob

I am trying to prove the following fact while learning the [J-Bob language](https://github.com/the-little-prover/j-bob): that any non-negative natural number is positive (with my proof attempts below).

The fact seems simple enough. However, I encountered some obvious problems. In the proof below, there seems to be no good place to expand any definitions.

```
(J-Bob/prove (prelude)
  '(((dethm natp-positive (x)
       (if (natp x)
           (if (equal '0 x)
               'nil
               (equal (< '0 x) 't))
           't))
     nil
     ((Q) (natp x))
     )))
```

In particular, the two main functions `natp` and `<` seem to be primitive. They do not expand. In the scheme implementation of J-Bob, the two functions are defined as follows:

```
(define (natp x)
  (if (integer? x) (if (s.< x 0) 'nil 't) 'nil))
(define (< x y)
  (if (s.< (num x) (num y)) 't 'nil))
```

If I understand it correctly, a deeper issue is that the nats are not defined inductively. It seems that, in a situation like this, I cannot resort to induction on the nats to prove anything.

*My questions are:*

First, is there actually a way to use existing J-Bob axioms to prove that a nat+ is positive?

Second, if not, does this mean that there are facts about numbers that cannot be proved in J-Bob, and that the axioms are incomplete?

Third, is there a way to insert the above fact as an axiom (for the scheme implementation), and are there many other theorems like this that need to be inserted to prove things about numbers in J-Bob?

Comment: Every system$^*$ that can express the natural numbers is incomplete, as Gödel's incompleteness dictates.